# PHP Write and Read from Text File

Tags: php

I have an issue with writing and reading to text file.

I have to first write from a text file to another text file some values which I need to read again. Below are the code snippets:

Write to text file:

```
$fp = @fopen ("text1.txt", "r");

$fh = @fopen("text2.txt", 'a+');
        
if ($fp) {
 //for each line in file
    while(!feof($fp)) {
    //push lines into array
    $thisline = fgets($fp);
    $thisline1 = trim($thisline);
        
     $stringData = $thisline1. "\r\n";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
                    
                  fwrite($fh, "test");

                }
            }
fclose($fp);
fclose($fh);
```

Read from the written textfile

```
$page = join("",file("text2.txt"));
$kw = explode("\n", $page);
for($i=0;$i<count($kw);$i++){
             
 echo rtrim($kw[$i]);
               
}
```

But, if I am not mistaken due to the "/r/n" I used to insert the newline, when I am reading back, there are issues and I need to pass the read values from only the even lines to a function to perform other operations.

How do I resolve this issue? Basically, I need to write certain values to a textfile and then read only the values from the even lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you have issues with the even line numbers or with reading the file back in.

Here is the solution for the even line numbers.

```
$page = join("",file("text2.txt"));
$kw = explode("\n", $page);
for($i=0;$i<count($kw);$i++){

    $myValue = rtrim($kw[$i]);
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        echo $myValue;
    }

}
```